# Stripe Newbie trying to implement Stripe payment on iOS application

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, payment

I am a newbie in iOS, for my college project we decided to build a meal delivery app which will take payments. For that i thought of implementing Stripe payment. My initial submission would be simply to perform a dummy transaction.
So I went to the github resources folder and was reading the Readme section of Non-Card Payment examples
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/22.1.0/Example/Non-Card%20Payment%20Examples

Based on the instructions

- I created an account with Stripe
  but could not find the workspace file

If someone could help me out here or atleast point me to the right direction would be really helpful
Thank you
Zawad

Answer (score 0):

It supposes to be [the xcworkspace file at 2 layers above](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/22.1.0/Stripe.xcworkspace).

But nevertheless, you should follow this detailed Doc instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. The thing is I have gone through that link earlier and tried to install the pod, but couldnt as I am accessing a remote mac at my college. Will it work if someone who has proper access install and share the podfile?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using SwiftUI and SPM for fast start up. Please watch the below video from Azam Sharp who talks about how it works and already has a remote node.js server to test.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De7EL_1jv0c

https://github.com/azamsharp/FruitStoreStripeAPI
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mango-persistent-organ

Let me know if you have any issues or questions!